# collection of collections is passed to function, gives ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, pass-by-reference

I have 4 collections, two contain a number of strings related to training codes. The other two collections contain a number of collections containing employee IDs and employee names. One of these sub-collections also includes training codes and a date the employee last completed the training.

I am trying to find training that hasn't been completed yet, so I am going through the collection of employees and the collection of training codes, checking the collection of last-completed-trainings for an entry. If there is no entry found, I create a collection with the employee's id, name, the training code, and a string indicating they have not completed the training yet, and then adding this information to a collection of training that needs to be completed.

The issue I'm having is that I get a 'ByRef argument type mismatch' error when calling the MissingTraining() function even though all the datatypes are declared correctly. The error highlights the Function GetItmsIncomplete() as Collection line in yellow and the word 'employee' in the If MissingTraining(employee, trainCode, ItmsInfo) Then line. I have confirmed each argument passed is the correct datatype with the Locals inspector, so I'm confused why this error is popping up.

Here is the main function:

```
Function GetItmsIncomplete(ByRef ItmsInfo As Collection, ByRef GemsInfo As Collection, ByRef ItmsRecurrent As Collection, ByRef ItmsStatic As Collection) As Collection
    
    ' ItmsInfo is collection of collection[6-digit-id,"F.Name L.Name",TrainCode,DateLastCompleted]
    ' GemsInfo is collection of collection[6-digit-id,9-digit-id,"L.Name, F.Name"]
    ' ItmsRecu is collection of TrainCodes that are recurrent. This list is meant to be compared using Left(comparisonCode,Len(thisCode)) for proper comparison
    ' ItmsStat is collection of TrainCodes that are one-time trainings. These values are meant to be compared using Left(comparisonCode,Len(thisCode)) for proper comparison
    
    Dim ItmsDue As New Collection
    Dim TrainingInfo As New Collection
    
    ' ItmsInfo does not contain incomplete training, so we need to check all employees in Gems, all codes from Static, and compare to Info to find incomplete training
    For Each employee In GemsInfo
        For Each trainCode In ItmsStatic
            If MissingTraining(employee, trainCode, ItmsInfo) Then
                Set TrainingInfo = Nothing
                TrainingInfo.Add employee(1)
                TrainingInfo.Add employee(3)
                TrainingInfo.Add trainCode
                TrainingInfo.Add "Incomplete"
                ItmsDue.Add TrainingInfo
            End If
        Next trainCode
        ' also grab incomplete Recurrent training
        For Each trainCode In ItmsRecurrent
            ' TR* and [REDACTED]* training is not required for everyone, so skip it
            If Left(trainCode, 2) <> "TR" And Left(trainCode, 7) <> "[REDACTED]" Then
                If MissingTraining(employee, trainCode, ItmsInfo) Then
                    Set TrainingInfo = Nothing
                    TrainingInfo.Add employee(1)
                    TrainingInfo.Add employee(3)
                    TrainingInfo.Add trainCode
                    TrainingInfo.Add "Incomplete"
                    ItmsDue.Add TrainingInfo
                End If
            Else
                ' TODO - TR-* training is required for those that have completed TR00*
            End If
        Next trainCode
    Next employee
    
    Set GetItmsIncomplete = ItmsDue
    
End Function
```

Here is the MissingTraining() function:

```
Function MissingTraining(ByRef employee As Collection, trainCode As Variant, ByRef ItmsInfo As Collection) As Boolean
    ' employee [ItmsId,LmsId,"L.Name, F.Name"]
    ' training [ItmsId,"F.Name L.Name",TrainCode,LastComp]
    For Each training In ItmsInfo
        If training(1) = employee(1) And Left(training(3), Len(trainCode)) = trainCode Then
            MissingTraining = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next training
    MissingTraining = True
End Function
```

I tried googling the error in relation to collections of collections with no results that look related. I also searched stackoverflow for a question that looks related, but I don't see anything mentioning the byref mismatch error in relation to collections of collections.

I also tried changing passing the whole employee collection to just the employee id as a string, but got exactly the same result including the blue highlight on the word 'employee'.

The strange part is that I have passed this exact set of data in exactly the same way to a similar function in a previous section of my project when running through a different list of trainings, and did not have any errors. I am confused how this is different from the working part. (yes, I have confirmed I have declared, looped, passed, and ByRef'd exactly the same thing in exactly the same way in the previous part) so I'm just confused.

Comment: Where are `employee, trainCode` declared?  Can you include those declarations?

Comment: FYI "List" is not a type in VBA, so it's not clear exactly what you mean when you refer to variables as being "list of xxx".  By "list" do you mean Collection?

Comment: Similarly what is (eg) `[ItmsId,LmsId,"L.Name, F.Name"]` An array, or ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Good point! I have edited my post to correct my nounage. Yes, i mean 'Collection' when i say 'list'. [ItmsId,LmsId,"L.Name, F.Name"] is a note to myself telling me the order or information stored in the named collection. employee and trainCode are declared when building the GemsInfo,  ItmsStatic, and ItmsRecurrent collections. I did confirm in the Locals window that all the datatypes are correct immediately before the line that throws the error.

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit` ?  Are `employee` and `trainCode`  Globals?

Comment: @TimWilliams (no to both) Wait hold up... does 'For Each In collection' not include the type from the source? Why would you ever need or want a For Each with a different type than what you put into it? Either way... Like I said, Locals reports employee to be of type 'Variant/Object/Collection' the line before the error, so I'm not sure why it thinks it's not a Collection even though the Locals says it is.

Comment: For Each only uses the variable you provide - it doesn’t auto-create one of the correct type.   Since you’re not using option explicit it will default to using a Variant type

Answer (score 0):

You've not declared `employee` inside `GetItmsIncomplete` (and it's not a Global)
If you were using `Option Explicit` you'd get a compile-time error warning you about that.

Without `Option explicit`, `employee` is spun up as a `Variant`, so it can't be passed to a method which expects that argument to be of type `Collection`.

Always using `Option Explicit` will save you from this type of problem.

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.